# Image Cache mechanism to store and retrieve effectively

Tags: image, spring-boot, caching

I have a requirement that when I scan a UPC(Product code) from box the item image and item details to be shown in the screen.
What is the best possible way of storing the image files(70 kb each) so that the performance is better ie the moment people scan the image should be shown without delay.kindly 
Suggest me the best architecture.

FrontEnd:React native
Db: Informix
BackEnd:SpringBoot

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on your requirement and feasibility, though you can use LOB or BLOB to store files in the database, for me storing a file in the database would be the last option to do.

I would rather prefer to store their path in the database and I will place them in file system **placing files in the database makes database heavy and requires more tablespaces for databases, consequently, every backup of DB also becomes heavy**, even for viewing a file needs coding.

if you don't have too many files then you can go for it otherwise you will have to plan it carefully to store them in database.

Comment: I have around 1Tb of image the response time has to be very quick.I am looking after some good approach by which without more cost we can achieve. Is there by any chance elastic-search be used ?? I wanted a list of approcahes so that i can go for a discussion with my stake holders. Thanks @Shailesh  . Always welcome for new approaches

Comment: considering your scenario, I will not put images in the database, keep them on the file system, in case you are using the cloud, S3 bucket would be appropriate, only put the path in the database as one column and name is in another column, and in the case in future, you change filesystem path, then simply update the column.